# JW Player 6 - Auto playlist creation based on videos in folder

Tags: php, automation, jwplayer

What I have

- PHP 5.3
- JW Player 6.4

Who is this for

- I use this just to validated videos, instead of writing the code for the playlist. I put all the videos in a folder and they show up on the playlist, Nice and easy.

The problem

- The working script which can be found here [JW Player 5.10 Auto Folder Script](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/using-playlists/11409/automatic-playlist-script/) works with JW Player 5.10, however 6.0+ is need now. An upgrade which I have delayed long enough.

The first part of the code:

```
 <?php
$path ="./webvideos/test/";
$path2="./webvideos/test/";
$folder = opendir($path);
$start="<asx version='3.0'>n<title>Example ASX playlist</title>";
$Fnm = "$path./playlist.xml";
$inF = fopen($Fnm,"w");
fwrite($inF,$start."n");
while( $file = readdir($folder) ) {
     if (($file != '.')&&($file != '..')&&($file != 'index.htm')){
     $result="<entry>n<title>$file</title>n<ref href='$path2$file'/>n<param name='image' value='preview.jpg'/>n</entry>n";
         fwrite($inF,$result);
     }
}
fwrite($inF,"</asx>");
closedir($folder);
fclose($inF);
?>
```

I have checked the XML file with in the "test" folder and it is there, so there is not problem there.

This part of the code below allows you to download the video, (Right Click and Save). This works as well.

```
<?php
$dir = opendir("$path");
while($file = readdir($dir)) {
if(($file == "index.htm") || ($file == ".") || ($file == "..")){} else {
echo
"<a title='".$file."' href='".$path.$file."'>".$file."</a><br/>";
}
}
closedir($dir);
?>
```

The code below is for the player it self.

```
<div class="video" id="player"></div><!--/video-->
<script>
    jwplayer("player").setup({
    height: 550,
    listbar: {
    position: 'bottom',
    size: 200
    },
    width: 768,
    playlist:'playlistfile=playlist.xml&image=preview.jpg&playlist=bottom',             

});
</script>
```

Here I am not sure, I have tried various different possibility but no solutions as. I.e. unable to load play list is the common error I get, once I got unable to load RSS feed. I am not an expert with PHP but it appears to be the player section as I have tested the XML read and I am able to download the videos as well. I have sent a support email but still waiting, either way, I have found this to be a priceless tool for me and I am sure with will help other in Video Production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Script:

```
<?php
$path ="videos/test/";
$xmlfile = "$path/playlist.rss";
$path2="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."$path";
$folder = scandir($path);
$files = array();
foreach($folder as $file){
    if($file == '.' OR $file == '..' OR $file == 'index.htm'){}else{
        $files[$file] = filemtime($path.'/'.$file);     
    }
}
ksort($files);
//use asort to sort from old to new
$output="<rss version='2.0' xmlns:jwplayer='http://rss.jwpcdn.com/'><channel>";
foreach($files as $file => $date){
$output .= "" . PHP_EOL . 
"<item>" . PHP_EOL . "<title>$file</title>" . PHP_EOL . "<description>$file</description>" . PHP_EOL . "<jwplayer:image>./preview.jpg</jwplayer:image>" . PHP_EOL . "<jwplayer:source file='$path/$file' />" . PHP_EOL . "</item>" . PHP_EOL . "" . PHP_EOL;
}
$output .= "</channel>
</rss>";
file_put_contents($xmlfile,$output);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the playlist being generated is an ASX playlist. JW6 only supports mRSS.